# Python not parsing JSON API return prettily

Tags: python, json, macos

I reviewed a handful of the questions related to mine and found this slightly unique. I'm using Python 2.7.1 on OS X 10.7. One more note: I'm more of a hacker than developer.

I snagged the syntax below from [Python documentation](http://docs.python.org/library/json.html) to try to do a "Pretty Print:"

```
date = {}
data = urllib2.urlopen(url)
s = json.dumps(data.read(), sort_keys=True, indent=4)
print '\n'.join([l.rstrip() for l in s.splitlines()])
```

I expected using the rstrip / splitlines commands would expand out the calls like in the example.

Also, not sure if it's relevant, but when tring to pipe the output to `python -mjson.tool` the reply is `No JSON object could be decoded`

Here's a snippet of the cURL output I'm trying to parse:

```
{"data":[{"name":"Site Member","created_at":"2012-07-24T11:22:04-07:00","activity_id":"500ee7cbbaf02xxx8e011e2e",
```

And so on.

The main objective is to make this mess of data more legible so I can learn from it and start structuring some automatic scraping of data based on arguments. Any guidance to get me from green to successful is a huge help.

Thanks,
mjb

Comment: You should post example output, and explain what's wrong with the output you get.

Comment: You should have no need for `.rstrip()` there. `rstrip` removes trailing whitespace, which `json.dumps` doesn't introduce. What's wrong with just `json.dumps(d, sort_keys=True, indent=4)`?

Comment: Not very automated, but you [http://jsonlint.com/](http://jsonlint.com/) will pretty-print json for you.

Comment: @colin - the cURL output is identical to the output I get using my current python script.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The output of the urllib2.urlopen().read() is a string and needs to be converted to an object first before you can call `json.dumps()` on it.

Modified code:

```
date = {}
data = urllib2.urlopen(url)
data_obj = json.loads(data.read())
s = json.dumps(data_obj, sort_keys=True, indent=4)
print s
```

Comment: That does it! Thanks so much. I appreciate the specific explanation so I can begin to breakdown the specific problems here. I'm a learn-by-trial-and-fire dev guy.